# DispatcherTimer Gui freezes

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am using DispatcherTimer. Sending data to a chart. As the data on the graph accumulates, the gui freezes. DispatcherTimer not running in a separate thread? If it runs in a separate thread, what exactly is the problem?

MyTimer Code

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(clearOK == 1)
            {
                AxisX_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                AxisY_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                AxisZ_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                clearOK = 0;
            }
            if (DataParse.grapFlag == 1)
            {
                DataParse.grapFlag = 0;
                double[] ys1 = DataParse.xData.ToArray();
                double[] xs1 = new double[ys1.Length];
                double[] ys2 = DataParse.yData.ToArray();
                double[] xs2 = new double[ys2.Length];
                double[] ys3 = DataParse.zData.ToArray();
                double[] xs3 = new double[ys3.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < ys1.Length; i++)
                {
                    startTime = startTime.AddMilliseconds(5);
                    xs1[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                    xs2[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                    xs3[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                }


                AxisX_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs1, ys1, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                AxisX_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                AxisX_Graphic.Render();

                AxisY_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs2, ys2, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                AxisY_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                AxisY_Graphic.Render();

                AxisZ_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs3, ys3, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                AxisZ_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                AxisZ_Graphic.Render();
                DataParse.xData.Clear();
                DataParse.yData.Clear();
                DataParse.zData.Clear();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

I changed the code as follows but it still freezes.

I'm using System.Threading.Timer

```
void TTimerTick(object state)
    {
        AxisX_Graphic.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (clearOK == 1)
                {
                    AxisX_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                    AxisY_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                    AxisZ_Graphic.plt.Clear();
                    clearOK = 0;
                }
                if (DataParse.grapFlag == 1)
                {
                    DataParse.grapFlag = 0;
                    double[] ys1 = DataParse.xData.ToArray();
                    double[] xs1 = new double[ys1.Length];
                    double[] ys2 = DataParse.yData.ToArray();
                    double[] xs2 = new double[ys2.Length];
                    double[] ys3 = DataParse.zData.ToArray();
                    double[] xs3 = new double[ys3.Length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < ys1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        startTime = startTime.AddMilliseconds(5);
                        xs1[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                        xs2[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                        xs3[i] = startTime.ToOADate();
                    }


                    AxisX_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs1, ys1, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                    AxisX_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                    AxisX_Graphic.Render();

                    AxisY_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs2, ys2, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                    AxisY_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                    AxisY_Graphic.Render();

                    AxisZ_Graphic.plt.PlotScatter(xs3, ys3, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 36, 71, 134), markerSize: 1);
                    AxisZ_Graphic.plt.AxisAuto();
                    AxisZ_Graphic.Render();
                    DataParse.xData.Clear();
                    DataParse.yData.Clear();
                    DataParse.zData.Clear();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }));

        
    }
```

Comment: The Tick handler runs in the thread in which the DispatcherTimer was created, typically the UI thread. That is why you use it. If the Tick handler performs a lengthy operation, it will obviously block the UI thread.

Comment: How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Use some other timer class, or make the Tick handler `async` and run and await an async Task.

Comment: Can you explain with an example? I'm new and I don't understand some things.

Comment: I shared the version I changed above. Would you check ?

Comment: Why should that make a difference? Due to the Dispatcher.Invoke call, the whole code in the TTimerTick method still runs in the UI thread.

Comment: Since the code in the TTimer sends data to the chart, if I don't include it in "Dispatcher.Invoke" it gives an error that the stretch in the different ui thread is not accessible. What can I do in this situation.

Comment: Run any time-consuming code in a background thread, e.g. that of a Timer or a Task. Run only those code parts in the UI thread (i.e. a Dispatcher action) that actually need access to the UI.